# Python - Merge many big numpy arrays with unknown shape, that would not fit in memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, merge

Let's suppose I have a large number of NumPy arrays saved as files (`np.save`(), ".npy" files). All these have shape e.g. (*n*,20), where I don't know *n* without opening the file. *n* is different for every file.

I want to merge these into a single dataset, and then using a set of selection methods split it into three different numpy arrays written on the disk.

Usually I would loop over all files and use `np.concatenate()`. However the final array is likely not to fit in memory.

The other option I have is to use `np.memmap()`, which I am absolutely not so sure how it works. To my understanding, I'd have to do something like that:

```
a = np.memmap('output.npy',dtype='float64',mode='w+',shape=(N,20))
for i,f in enumerate(myfiles):
    a[i,:] = np.load(f)
a.flush()
# And then find a way to split "a" into three, does the following work?
part_one = a[ [0,2,10,42,58] , : ]
```

The problem is that I don't know *N*, the final number of rows. Therefore I would need to open each file, read number of rows, close the file, sum all the number of rows before declaring the memmap. Which is highly inefficient, and there must be a better method.

Do you have any suggestion on this problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By "read number of rows" are you just reading the header or the entire array? If its just the header, that seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I use `array.shape()`, which I guess is the "header", right?

Comment: ...after an `np.load`?

Comment: Yes. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Yes, posted a way to read the shape from the file's header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.npy` file specification](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html#format-specification-version-1-0) defines the header for npy files. I couldn't find an already-baked way to read it, but the format is easy and you can pull the information out yourself. The file information is encoded in a python `dict` including a `shape` tuple. This is a short read of the top of the file and will be much faster than reading in the data.

```
import struct
import ast

# structs to decode .npy file header consisting of a "magic"
# string verifying the file type, major and minor version numbers,
# header length, and literal string representation of a python dict
# holding file's type and shape.

npy_magic = b"\x93NUMPY"

npy_v1_header = struct.Struct(
        "<"   # little-endian encoding
        "6s"  # 6 byte magic string
        "B"   # 1 byte major number
        "B"   # 1 byte minor number
        "H"   # 2 byte header length
        # ... header string follows
)

npy_v2_header = struct.Struct(
        "<"   # little-endian encoding
        "6s"  # 6 byte magic string
        "B"   # 1 byte major number
        "B"   # 1 byte minor number
        "L"   # 4 byte header length
        # ... header string follows
)

def read_npy_file_header(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        buf = fp.read(npy_v1_header.size)
        magic, major, minor, hdr_size = npy_v1_header.unpack(buf)
        if magic != npy_magic:
            raise IOError("Not an npy file")
        if major not in (0,1):
            raise IOError("Unknown npy file version")
        if major == 2:
            fp.seek(0)
            buf = fp.read(npy_v2_header.size)
            magic, major, minor, hdr_size = npy_v2_header.unpack(buf)
        return ast.literal_eval(fp.read(hdr_size).decode('ascii'))


# test
from glob import glob
for fn in glob('*.npy'):
    print(fn, read_npy_file_header(fn))
```

Comment: ""\x93NUMPY"" and "<6sBBL". What are those? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The `struct` module lets you read and write binary data. The .npy header is defined as some binary data followed by a string representation of a python dict holding the array information you need. "<6sBBL" reads the binary part of the header so we know where the dict part is. `\x93NUMPY` is just a type verifier to make sure this really is a numpy file.